# Simple Post Request Using Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I have created a Lookup activity to parse through a large array similar to the one below.  I then run a ForEach activity to break these down into single items.  The @item output from the ForEach activity looks like the below.  I now would like to use Azure Functions to pick up this object for future transformation.  How would I write the POST request in C#.

Output from the ForEach activity
[
"variableName": "Variable",
"value":{
"id:" 2,
"Name": "John"
"Age": 30
}
]

Original Data:
[
{
"ID": 1,
"Name": "John",
"Age" : 30
},
{
"ID": 2,
"Name": "Rachel",
"Age" : 35
},
{
"ID": 3,
"Name": "Jerome",
"Age" : 40
},
{
"ID": 4,
"Name": "Sue",
"Age" : 45
}
]

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try use http client?

Comment: Did you have have a look at my response below? If it resolves your questions, kindly mark it as the accepted answer. Else kindly provide more details on where you are stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an Azure function as a step from Data factory. [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLH81MFmKCg). You can pass any data in the body of the request. You Azure function will be a simple http triggered function and you can code whatever logic you want in it.